# Rails remote_ip always 127.0.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3. I want to get client ip. I am using this method: request.remote_ip and always getting 127.0.0.2. Why ? ( also tested on TorProject)

Comment: That's the [loopback device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback). I would guess you have some kind of proxy sitting on your server between Rails and the Internet.

Comment: I am using passenger and nginx server. I have cheap shell host.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend where you're testing from. If it's in production and you're trying this off of an external computer(that's not on the same network as the server) it should work. Otherwise yes, it should be some sort of proxy or gateway translating the address.

Comment: SOLVED. It was server trouble. I have wrote to admin and he fixed it. Thank you

Comment: glad to hear, best of luck with your site.